# How to loop again while there is no input?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I was hoping you could help me with my java code.

Here is the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> team = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> pos = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Player Name: ");
        name.add(in.nextLine());
        do {
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Name\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Player Name: ");
            name.add(in.nextLine());
        }
        while (name.contains(""));

        System.out.println("Enter Basketball Team: ");
        team.add(in.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter your Position: ");
        pos.add(in.nextLine());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(name.get(i) + "\t" + team.get(i) + "\t\t" + pos.get(i));
    }
}
```

What I'm trying achieve is that, in each scanner you are required to input something.

Comment: Can you explain with examples what is happening?

Comment: `while(name.contains(""));` looks dodgy.  Debug your code and see what the value of `name` is.  Probably better to have `while(name.equals(""));`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it work one time but when I don't input anything the 2nd time, it automatically proceed to the other scanner. I want it to continuously ask to enter something if it doesn't have any input.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that you are adding to a ArrayList.  Get the input from `nextLine` into a String and check its value.  If OK then add to the ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

The reason it keeps looping is because you have this condition: `while(name.contains(""));` this means that after you entered an empty line it will have this value "" in the array as it adds this value regardless if the value is valid or not. This means that you will keep looping in this do-while loop.

The easiest way I can think of to fix this is to have a separate boolean value to check if the input is different than empty space, and then only after it passes this validation you will add this to the name array.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a runnable demo console application which shows another way you can do this sort of thing by using a single ArrayList (or List Interface). You would utilize a **Player** class and then use a List of Player instead of three parallel ArrayList's:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is the runnable code. Each prompt (Player Name, Team Name, and Player position) contains validation (via length) and if any prompt entry is found to to be invalid then the User can re-enter again.  *Be sure to read all the comments in code*:

```
public class BasketBallPlayersDemo {

    // Open a keyboard input Stream (can be used in any class):
    public final static java.util.Scanner USER_INPUT = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    // OS System related terminal newLine character(s) (can be used in any class):
    public final static String LS = System.lineSeparator();

    // List Interface of Player. Holds instances of Player (can be used in any class):
    public static java.util.List<Player> players = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    // Application entry point...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for
           statics except for what we want.       */
        new BasketBallPlayersDemo().startApp(args);
    }

    // Application start method:
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Boolean flag used to end Player entry.
        boolean done = false;
        // Counter used to keep track of the current player number.
        int playerCount = 0;

        /* Loop so that continuous players can be entered. If 'd' 
           is entered instead of a player name then player entry
           is halted and a players list is displayed but only if
           instances of Player have been added to the List.    */
        while (!done) {
            playerCount++;  // Increment player count.

            // The Player Name Prompt:
            String name = "";
            while (name.isEmpty()) {
                // Prompt Display:
                System.out.print("Please Enter Player Name #" + playerCount + " ('d' for Done): -> ");
                // User Input. Trim off any possible leading/trailing whitespaces:
                name = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
                // Is 'd' for done supplied?
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                    //Yes...set flag to true and exit prompt loop:
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
                /* Validation. If the length of Player Name is less than 3 then
                   inform of invalid entry and allow User to try again:  */
                if (name.length() < 3) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry! You must enter a proper name! "
                            + "Try again..." + LS);
                    name = "";  // Empty variable to ensure prompt re-loop.
                }
            }
            /* If 'd' for `done` was not supplied in the above prompt
               then carry on into `if` code block otherwise exit player
               entry loop:            */
            if (!done) {
                // Capitalize the first character of supplied name(s):
                name = capitalizeAll(name);

                //Prompt for Team Name:
                String team = "";
                while (team.isEmpty()) {
                    // Prompt Display:
                    System.out.print("Please Enter Player Team Name: -> ");
                    // User Input. Trim off any possible leading/trailing whitespaces:
                    team = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
                    /* Validation. If the length of Team Name is less than 3 then
                       inform of invalid entry and allow User to try again:  */
                    if (team.length() < 3) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Entry! You must enter a proper Team Name! "
                                + "Try again..." + LS);
                        team = "";  // Empty variable to ensure prompt re-loop.
                    }
                }
                // Capitalize the first character of supplied Team Name(s):
                team = capitalizeAll(team);

                //Prompt for Player Position:
                String position = "";
                while (position.isEmpty()) {
                    // Prompt Display:
                    System.out.print("Please Enter Player Position: -> ");
                    // User Input. Trim off any possible leading/trailing whitespaces:
                    position = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
                    /* Validation. If the length of Player Position is less than
                       3 then inform of invalid entry and allow User to try again:  */
                    if (position.length() < 3) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Entry! You must enter a position! "
                                + "Try again..." + LS);
                        position = "";  // Empty variable to ensure prompt re-loop.
                    }
                }
                /* Capitalize the first character of each word for supplied 
                   Player Position:  */
                position = capitalizeAll(position);
                System.out.println();  // Blank Line in Console Window.

                // Add player instance to List via Player class constructor:
                players.add(new Player(name, team, position));
            }
        }

        // Display Players in Console Window (if there are any):
        if (!players.isEmpty()) {
            // First, Sort Players by `Team Names` in Ascending order (optional):
            sortByTeams();

            System.out.println();               // Blank Line in Console Window.
            System.out.println("Players:");     // Display Title.
            /* Used to indicate first Player instance so to 
               apply a Header to the display.          */
            int idx = 0;
            // Iterate through the List of Player Instances:
            for (Player p : players) {
                // Is this the first instance?
                if (idx == 0) {
                    /* Yes...Then display the Header and current instance of 
                       Player. Note how true is supplied to the toTableString()
                       method so to display Header.      */
                    System.out.println(p.toTableString(true));
                }
                else {
                    // Otherwise...just display the current instance of Player.
                    System.out.println(p.toTableString());
                }
                idx++;  // Incremant counter.
            }

            // Example how you could display All Players from a specific Team:
            System.out.println();
            String team = "";
            while (team.isEmpty()) {
                // Prompt Display:
                System.out.print("Please enter the Team Name to list Players of: -> ");
                // User Input. Trim off any possible leading/trailing whitespaces:
                team = USER_INPUT.nextLine().trim();
                /* Validation. If the Team is not in the List then inform of 
                   invalid entry and allow User to try again:  */
                boolean found = false;
                for (Player p : players) {
                    if (p.getPlayerTeam().equalsIgnoreCase(team)) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry! Team (" + team + ") Not Found! "
                            + "Try again..." + LS);
                    team = "";  // Empty variable to ensure prompt re-loop.
                }
                else {
                    idx = 0;
                    for (Player p : players) {
                        if (p.getPlayerTeam().equalsIgnoreCase(team)) {
                            if (idx == 0) {
                                System.out.println(p.toTableString(true));
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println(p.toTableString());
                            }
                            idx++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Misc. Methods:
    // Captialize all words in String (Java8+ | Uses Stream):
    private String capitalizeAll(String inputString) {
        if (inputString == null || inputString.isEmpty()) {
            return inputString;
        }
        return java.util.Arrays.stream(inputString.split("\\s+"))
                .map(t -> t.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + t.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    // Player Sort Methods. Use whichever you desire or none at all.
    // Method to Sort players by `Player Names` (in Ascending order):
    private void sortByNames() {
        java.util.Collections.sort(players, (Player u1, Player u2)
                -> u1.getPlayerName().compareTo(u2.getPlayerName()));
    }

    // Method to Sort players by `Player Teams` (in Ascending order):
    private void sortByTeams() {
        java.util.Collections.sort(players, (Player u1, Player u2)
                -> u1.getPlayerTeam().compareTo(u2.getPlayerTeam()));
    }

    // Method to Sort players by `Player Positions` (in Ascending order):
    private void sortByPositions() {
        java.util.Collections.sort(players, (Player u1, Player u2)
                -> u1.getPlayerPosition().compareTo(u2.getPlayerPosition()));
    }

    /**
     * The Player Class:
     *
     * Better to be a class (.java) file of its own rather than an inner class.
     * Only used here as inner class for demo purpose.
     */
    public class Player {

        private String playerName;
        private String playerTeam;
        private String playerPosition;

        // Constructor:
        public Player(String name, String team, String pos) {
            this.playerName = name;
            this.playerTeam = team;
            this.playerPosition = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return playerName + ", " + playerTeam + ", " + playerPosition;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a table style String.
         *
         * @param applyHeader (boolean - optional) Default is false and when
         *                    called, no header is supplied before the instance
         *                    data. If boolean true is supplied then header text
         *                    is applied along with the instance data.
         *
         * @return (String) Current class member instance data with or without a
         *         Header string.
         */
        public String toTableString(boolean... applyHeader) {
            boolean addHeader = false;
            if (applyHeader.length > 0) {
                addHeader = applyHeader[0];
            }
            String header = String.format("%-12s %-14s %-12s%n", "Name", "Team", "Position");
            String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"))
                    + BasketBallPlayersDemo.LS;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            if (addHeader) {
                sb.append(underline);
                sb.append(header);
                sb.append(underline);
            }
            sb.append(String.format("%-12s %-14s %-12s", playerName, playerTeam, playerPosition));

            return sb.toString();
        }

        // Class Getter and Setter methods:
        public String getPlayerName() {
            return playerName;
        }

        public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
            this.playerName = playerName;
        }

        public String getPlayerTeam() {
            return playerTeam;
        }

        public void setPlayerTeam(String playerTeam) {
            this.playerTeam = playerTeam;
        }

        public String getPlayerPosition() {
            return playerPosition;
        }

        public void setPlayerPosition(String playerPosition) {
            this.playerPosition = playerPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a little helper function that receives a prompt and just loops until the user types something:

```
  public static String getResponse(String prompt) {
    String response = "";
    do {
      System.out.print(prompt);
      response = in.nextLine().trim();
    } while (response.length() == 0);
    return response;
  }
```

Here it is in use. Note that I moved the scanner outside of main() and made it static so that it can be used in all methods:

```
class Main { 
  
  public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> team = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> pos = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++) {
        String newName = getResponse("Enter Player Name: ");
        String newTeam = getResponse("Enter Basketball Team: ");
        String newPosition = getResponse("Enter your Position: ");        
        name.add(newName);
        team.add(newTeam);
        pos.add(newPosition);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(name.get(i) + "\t" + team.get(i) + "\t\t" + pos.get(i));
    }
  }

  public static String getResponse(String prompt) {
    String response = "";
    do {
      System.out.print(prompt);
      response = in.nextLine().trim();
    } while (response.length() == 0);
    return response;
  }
  
}
```